# Why does a loaded CSV set the value of object to a string

Tags: json, node.js, csv, filereader

So I have this code:

```
function _getAllArticles() {
    var result = [];
    result.push(new Article('./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg','Batman','A poster of batman', 100, 34.99));
    result.push(new Article('./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg', 'Batman2', 'A poster of batman2', 10, 124.99));
    result.push(new Article('./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg', 'Batman3', 'A poster of batman3', 25, 4.99));

    var converter = require('json-2-csv');
    var fs = require('fs')

    var test = [];

    converter.json2csv(result, function (err, csv) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(csv);
        test.push(csv);
    })
    fs.writeFile('file.csv', test, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
    });



    var fs = require('fs')
    var csvjson = require('csvjson');
    var data = fs.readFileSync('file.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    return csvjson.toObject(data);
}
```

As you can see I have object article where there are two attributes with numbertypes. But when I load the file the values of the attributes quantity and price are converted to a string. When I exceute this line of code`return csvjson.toObject(data);` and JSON.stringify it I get this:

```
[{"imageLocation":"./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg","title":"Batman","description":"A poster of batman","quantity":"34.99","price":"100"},{"imageLocation":"./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg","title":"Batman2","description":"A poster of batman2","quantity":"124.99","price":"10"},{"imageLocation":"./BatmanEpicWallpaper.jpg","title":"Batman3","description":"A poster of batman3","quantity":"4.99","price":"25"}]
```

As you can see the value of the attribute quantity and price are always with "" why is that so? Is it because of modules which I use (json-2-csv,csvjson)?

Here is where I stringify it:

```
 GetAllArticles: (req, res) => {
        var allArticles = _getAllArticles();

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(allArticles));  
        res.end();
    },
```

Comment: Both json2csv and csvjson maintain the number format. Do not stringify the output object, just check the typeOf(price) in final object.

Comment: @Aky_0788 where excatly do you mean to check the type? I need to stringfy it because I want to return res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');

Comment: The place where you are using JSON.stringify. Just check the type of this field, just want to know where might be problem

Comment: @Aky_0788 see edit.

Comment: @Aky_0788 Do you mean I should go through entire array and check if the attribute is number format

Comment: GetAllArticles: (req, res) => {
        var allArticles = _getAllArticles();

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        console.log(typeOf(allArticles.price))
        //res.write(JSON.stringify(allArticles));  
        res.end();
    },

Comment: @Aky_0788   Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143702/discussion-between-tizaljubavnisirodjena-and-aky-0788).